# Changing the code organization, so that was the same ID

Tags: python, django, payment-gateway, braintree

I have a Django application that uses Braintree payment gateway.
My problem is that the subscription ID and the ID history subscription differ from each other.
I think that the problem may also be the cancellation of the subscription.

Here is ID form created subscription: id: u'hjg8gm', and here is ID from status history id: u'9ppndw'. They are different, but I want them to be the same.

```
def create_subscription():
    try:
        result = braintree.Subscription.create({
            "payment_method_token": payment_method_token,
            "plan_id": "myPlanId"
        })
        if result.is_success:
            return result
    except braintree.exceptions.NotFoundError:
        return "No customer found."

def get_subscription_history():
    result = create_subscription()
    history = braintree.Subscription.find(result.subscription.id)
    return history

def cancel_subscription():
    result = create_subscription()
    cancel = braintree.Subscription.cancel(result.subscription.id)
    return cancel

def create_subscription_view(request):
    return render(request, "sheet/subscript.html", {'subscript': create_subscription()})

def get_history(request):
    return render(request, "sheet/history.html", {"history": get_subscription_history()})

def cancel_subscription_view(request):
    return render(request, "sheet/cancel.html", {"cancel": cancel_subscription()})
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't understand your question. What is different? Can you show me exactly what two attributes you expect to be the same but aren't on exactly what two objects? Also, as I metioned in my answer to your other question, you'd be better off [contacting Braintree support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/) and [following the Braintree recurring billing guide](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+python/guides/recurring-billing).

Comment: The answer is correct, you're create a new subscription in every different method, so the IDs won't match. You need to create a subscription only once, then store the ID somewhere, and use that to `find` it instead of the ID from a new subscription.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any experience with Braintree. But as I have observed your code. On each method your're creating a new subscription.

#### May these steps will help you:

**1.** Create subscription only on:

```
def create_subscription_view(request):
    return render(request, "sheet/subscript.html", {'subscript': create_subscription()})
```

**2.** Then save subscription id to non-volatile memory. (e.g: in database)

**3.** Fetch `subscription_id` from database and request to Braintree for details:

```
# An example to fetch subscription id
subscription_id = SubscriptionModel.objects.filter(user=request.user)[:1].subscription_id
# Request to braintree for subscription_id
history = braintree.Subscription.find(subscription_id)
cancel  = braintree.Subscription.cancel(subscription_id)
```

Sorry, If my suggestion don't work!